# Handling overlapping cards on a timeline

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a simple timeline on my website with cards. The cards get placed on the timeline using a simple function. But some of the cards overlap. I want to make it so if a card overlaps it gets put *under* the original card. And if it still overlaps it gets put *above* the timeline. But I'm not sure how to implement this correctly.

Here's some code I have up until now:

-- Calculating card positions --

```js
const calculateCardPosition = (card) => {
    const start = -13800000000;
    const end = 0;
    let x = ((card.date - start) / (end - start)) * 100;

    if (x < 10) {
      x = x + 10;
    } else if (x > 90) {
      x = x - 10;
    }

    return { x };
  };
```

-- Timeline section --

```
<section id="timeline" className="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 py-10">
          <div className="container mx-auto h-96 bg-sections-intro-light dark:bg-sections-intro-dark">
            <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold text-center mb-8">Timeline</h2>

            {/* Timeline */}
            <div className="relative">
              {/* Timeline line */}
              <div className="border-2 border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-700 absolute w-full h-0 left-0 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2"></div>

              {/* Timeline cards */}
              <ul className="gap-4 absolute top-0 left-0 w-full">
                {timelineContent.map((item) => (
                  <li
                    id={item.id}
                    key={item.id}
                    className={`bg-white dark:bg-gray-700 rounded-md shadow-md p-2 cursor-pointer ${
                      activeCard === item.date ? "border-2 border-blue-500" : ""
                    } timeline-card`}
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      left: `${calculateCardPosition(item).x}%`,
                      transform: "translateX(-50%)",
                      width: "150px",
                    }}
                    onClick={() => scrollToSection(item.scrollTo)}
                    onMouseEnter={() => handleCardHover(item.date)}
                    onMouseLeave={() => handleCardHover(null)}
                  >
                    <h3 className="text-base font-semibold">{item.title}</h3>
                    {activeCard === item.date && <p className="mt-2 text-sm">{item.description}</p>}
                  </li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

[image: Timeline]

Answer (score 0):

Run through the list of cards and calculate if they would overlap by first getting their `x` values.

```js
const activeCard = null;

const timelineContent = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'Foo',
    description: 'Description',
    date: -12800000000,
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Bar',
    description: 'Description',
    date: -10800000000,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Baz',
    description: 'Description',
    date: -9800000000,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Foo bar',
    description: 'Description',
    date: -800000000,
  },
];

const calculateCardPosition = (card) => {
  const start = -13800000000;
  const end = 0;
  let x = ((card.date - start) / (end - start)) * 100;

  if (x < 10) {
    x = x + 10;
  } else if (x > 90) {
    x = x - 10;
  }

  return { x };
};

// Build an intermediary array with `x` positions and default `y` positions.
const timelineContent1 = timelineContent.map(card => ({
  ...card,
  x: calculateCardPosition(card).x,
  y: 0,
}));

function App() {
  const container = React.useRef(null);
  // Have a state of our transformed timeline content with updated `y` positions.
  const [timelineContent2, setTimelineContent] = React.useState(timelineContent1);
  
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // Get the current width of the position container, the timeline element.
    const { width } = container.current.getBoundingClientRect();

    setTimelineContent(
      // Work through the list. `.slice(1)` since the first item will not need to be
      // altered.
      timelineContent1.slice(1).reduce(
        (accumulator, card, i) => {
          // Get the previous card's `x` and `y`.
          const { x: previousX, y: previousY } = accumulator[i];
          return accumulator.concat({
            ...card,
            // If the percentage × the container width is less than 150, then this card
            // would overlap, so add `3` (arbitrary for this example) to prevent the overlap.
            // Otherwise, use default `0`.
            y: (Math.abs(card.x - previousX) / 100) * width < 150
              ? previousY + 3
              : 0
          });
        },
        [timelineContent1[0]]
      )
    );
  }, [setTimelineContent, container]);

  return (
    <section id="timeline" className="bg-gray-100 dark:bg-gray-800 py-10">
      <div className="container mx-auto h-96 bg-sections-intro-light dark:bg-sections-intro-dark">
        <h2 className="text-3xl font-bold text-center mb-8">Timeline</h2>

        {/* Timeline */}
        <div className="relative" ref={container}>
          {/* Timeline line */}
          <div className="border-2 border-gray-300 dark:border-gray-700 absolute w-full h-0 left-0 top-1/2 transform -translate-y-1/2"></div>
          {/* Timeline cards */}
          <ul className="gap-4 absolute top-0 left-0 w-full">
            {timelineContent2.map((item, i) => (
              <li
                id={item.id}
                key={item.id}
                className={`bg-white dark:bg-gray-700 rounded-md shadow-md p-2 cursor-pointer ${
                  activeCard === item.date ? 'border-2 border-blue-500' : ''
                } timeline-card`}
                style={{
                  position: 'absolute',
                  top: `${item.y || 0}rem`,
                  left: `${item.x}%`,
                  transform: 'translateX(-50%)',
                  width: '150px',
                }}
              >
                <h3 className="text-base font-semibold">{item.title}</h3>
                {activeCard === item.date && (
                  <p className="mt-2 text-sm">{item.description}</p>
                )}
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

This is a proof-of-concept but for production code, you may need to listen for if the timeline container resizes, and recalculate the `y` positions accordingly. The `y` offset of `3rem` here is arbitrary and is something that might need to be calculated dynamically too in production code.